# Change request with no change

Tags: bug, documentation

It looks like a user has submitted a change request with no changes: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/10937

[image]

Comment: Someone likely already fixed it in a previous edit and the system didn't detect it correctly to reject it for edit conflicts. Oh the woes of allowing multiple proposed edits at the same time.