# Versions keeps being override by changes

Tags: bug, documentation

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/17554) I removed the versions for `GO JSON`.

[A different change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/17439), that did not impact the versions was then approved (probably it was created before my change was approved) and it override the versions again.

It looks like if:

- You create draft A and make change to versions
- Submit A
- Someone creates a draft B with no changes to versions
- Submits B
- A is approved (and versions are removed)
- B is approved

then versions are restored again.

Comment: Related to [Documentation treats edits as linear but they are not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328657/documentation-treats-edits-as-linear-like-qa-but-they-are-not).