# Very Confused by Documentation (multiple edits, reviews, and conflicting Accepts and Rejects)

Tags: discussion, documentation

I'm very confused about Documentation. This has been my experience so far:

- I started writing an introduction for the [Processing documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/processing/).
- Only when I was about to post, I realized that there was an existing introduction pending review.
- I accepted that review, but then I realized that their introduction was a bit misleading, so I edited it.
- My edit went into the improvement request queue.
- Then somebody else introduced a separate edit, which IMHO was pretty low quality. I rejected that edit with some hopefully useful feedback.
- Then a second person rejected my edit as conflicting with the edit that I had rejected.
- Then a third person approved the edit that I had rejected.

**Shouldn't the newer edit have been rejected as conflicting with my older (and imho, better quality) edit?**

This is further complicated by the fact that when I go to the Processing documentation, it takes me to my edits. So it looks like I "won". But then when I go there without being logged in, it shows the other edits, not mine.

And maybe I'm doing something wrong. When I go to edit the Processing topic, it shows me edits for both examples inside that topic- one of which contains my edit, the other contains somebody else's. When I hit submit, which am I editing? This whole thing makes me feel like a bit of an idiot.

I was pretty excited about Documentation, and I'm not the type to hate on new things just because they're different from what I'm used to. I'm very active in the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag, and was planning on being pretty active on Documentation. I **want** to like Documentation. But my experience so far has been very confusing and frustrating.

I'm not even sure I'm linking to this correctly, but here is my rejected edit: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/50783?draftId=43253

Here is the edit that I rejected, then my edit was rejected for conflicting with, but is the "winning" edit: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/61154

**My question is:** What am I supposed to do now? Do I resubmit my rejected edit? Do I edit the "winning" one (which imho is very low quality) to look more like mine? Do I forget it and move on- to what exactly? Why should I continue trying to improve documentation if I'm just going to be rejected in favor of lower-quality posts?

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I went crosseyed trying to follow the daisy chain of edits...

Comment: We're working on a more robust version of the review queue that should help make it easier to deal with multiple edits to the same section of a topic.

Comment: @Ares Sorry if I was confusing. But there are really only two that matter: the ones I linked to at the end of the post. The confusing bit is that my edit came first, then the second edit was separate from mine, I rejected that, somebody else rejected mine as conflicting with that second one, then somebody else accepted the second edit. I'm a little frustrated because imho the second edit is very low quality, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - Can you guys look into the UI/UX and introduce less text and less links.  The user experience is very hard to follow and navigate.  There are hundreds of links / buttons / hyperlinks that make using docs very difficult and mind numbing.

Comment: @JonH it'd be helpful if you could give more specifics in a separate meta post. I appreciate the feedback, but it's a little too general to be directly actionable.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - I will try to post a meta question today or tomorrow.

Comment: @JonH we're also going to be doing monthly user testing to improve the UI/UX moving forward, it will just take some time as we prioritize what to build/improve.

Comment: A very good title. It applies to the vast majority of posts on the topic.

Comment: In the mean time until a fix comes down, best bet is to resubmit your edit with an explanation like "the previous edit was of low quality. re-submitting my edit to fix this' and it'll likely get approved pretty quickly by someone

Comment: "I was pretty excited about Documentation, and I'm not the type to hate on new things just because they're different from what I'm used to. I'm very active in the processing tag, and was planning on being pretty active on Documentation. I **want** to like Documentation. But my experience so far has been very confusing and frustrating." ++++++++++   - ***THIS***.  Succinctly sums up everything that I feel right now.

Comment: [Documentation treats edits as linear but they are not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328657/documentation-treats-edits-as-linear-like-qa-but-they-are-not)

Comment: Documentation has to operate as a true Version Control System with intelligent merge functionality if it's to handle a really huge amount of changes.  This is very different from Q&A format.