# A strange documentation version number edit

Tags: bug, documentation

In this edit (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/37634) the edit summary says that the user is editing the version number to "All versions". It doesn't look like it does anything, because it is already set to "All versions". When I try to accept or reject the edit, I get the following error:

> An error has occurred during submission; please try again.

I have not seen this issue on any other edits.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error on 2 separate questions in the iOS Documentation tag, and I'm fairly certain it's a bug.

Example:  https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/8860

I saw one user postulate that it might be caused by two duplicate edits occurring, and the first one getting approved.  The second duplicate becomes bugged in this way, because there is no diff to show (the changes have already been added).

Edit: This question might have some more info: [Documentation treats edits as linear, like Q&A, but they are not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328657/documentation-treats-edits-as-linear-like-qa-but-they-are-not?rq=1)

[image]